# Compare a range of values with a single value in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

Maybe the title is a little confusing, but let me explain.

I have this table, where what I want is to check if any of the values of column Tools (D:D) are contained in Software (B2).

[image]

This would be the expected output, as "python" is contained in "Python 3.x", "netbeans" is contained in "Netbeans IDE" and so on.

[image]

So far, I've tried VLOOKUP, MATCH, and SEARCH, but I cannot make them work (I'm new in Excel, so I don't know much about formulas). Any ideas? I mean, if this is even possible.

Comment: I am either profoundly oblivious and don't understand your question; or I am ProfoundlyOblivious and you need to edit your question because your expected output doesn't match your criteria.  `"python" is contained in "Python 3.x", "netbeans" is contained in "Netbeans IDE" and so on` yet visual studio is no and it is contained in twice and Java is also no and it is contained once

Comment: ^ Agree that some of your output seems off - `visual studio` should be `Yes`, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to edit the image, as the "Found" column was filled manually. I'm on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case for COUNTIF and wildcards. In `E2` and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&D2&"*")>0,"Yes","No")
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your revision, if you are trying to search for a match for `B2` in `D:D`, you could do the following, which is the same approach as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109551/is-there-an-excel-formula-that-will-search-a-list-and-highlight-text-containing):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$10,B2)))>0,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I asked, but vice versa, this one search `D2` value on `B:B`, but I need to search `B2` in `D:D`, I think I can make it work, you gave me the precise idea.