# Excel: I'd like to find a formula that is able to tell me if my lookup/text value uses a set of terms in another column as a substring

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, string-matching

**Setup**

I have a list of user names in Worksheet 1.  Username in column B.  Examples:

- DefaultUser
- jsmith
- jdefaul
- btesting

In worksheet 2 I have a separate list of generic/commonly used name terms.  Worksheet name = **Controls**, terms stored in column A. Examples:

- default
- admin
- test

**Goal**

In worksheet 1, I would like to construct a formula for each row/user name that is able to tell me if the username within that row has a substring match with any of the terms from my generic name terms list.  Examples

- DefaultUser >> TRUE
- jsmith >> FALSE
- jdefaul >> FALSE (missing the 't')
- btesting >> TRUE

**What I have tried so far**

I have been googling for a good while now and all of various VLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX formulas I have found and tried aren't doing what I want.

- `=MATCH("*"&Controls!A:A&"*",B5,0)` >> which has given me results I can't even decipher
- `=INDEX(B4,MATCH(“*”&Controls!A:A&”*”,B4,0))` >> did not work at all (everything returned as #NAME?)
- `=VLOOKUP(B4,Controls!A:A,1,TRUE)` >> Was WAAAAY too loose on its matching, returning values with what appeared to be no rhyme or reason
- `=VLOOKUP("*"&B4&"*",Controls!A:A,1,FALSE)` >> was the closest but not quite there.  It only returned exact matches, because it is treating the lookup value as the substring component instead of my generic terms list.  If I could get the inverse behavior I'd be golden.

It feels like I am relatively close but can't quite reach the finish line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109551/is-there-an-excel-formula-that-will-search-a-list-and-highlight-text-containing):

Modify to fit your setup, but something like this:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1))))>0
```

[image]