# Count how many substrings are contained within a superstring

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

Counting the number of superstrings within a range contain a substring is easy in LibreOffice Calc and Excel. How to count how many times a superstring contains substrings within a range? In the example below, the times an Animal is contained in a set is COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5,"*"&B2&"*") for Dog, COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5,"*"&B3&"*") for Cat and so on. How do I count how many Animals of range B:B are contained in "Cat Dog Mouse Snake"? The answers on column D should be 3, 1, 1, 1.

[image]

Comment: You could probably adapt the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109551/is-there-an-excel-formula-that-will-search-a-list-and-highlight-text-containing), though I haven't tested it in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following formula in D2.  It is an array formula so you will need to use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when { } show up around the formula in the formula bar.  Note these cannot be added manually.

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2))))
```

Copy the cell and then paste in D3:D5.

Answer (score 0):

First put this UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function KeyKount(s As String, keywds As Range) As Long
    Dim temp As String, cell As Range

    KeyKount = 0
    temp = " " & s & " "
    For Each cell In keywds
        v = " " & cell.Text & " "
        If InStr(temp, v) > 0 Then KeyKount = KeyKount + 1
    Next cell
End Function
```

Then in a cell enter, for example:

```
=keykount(A2,B2:B10)
```

[image]

Comment: @BigBen  The previous was junk......................I have revised.

Comment: you just needed  to leave off the `>0` part: `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$10,A2)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner  I did not like my first answer, I was getting extra counts if one of my substrings was part of another substring.  This way I padded each substring with spaces.

Comment: Fair enough: `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$2:$B$10&" "," "&A2&" ")))`

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),B:B,0))))
```

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$B$2:$B$5&" "," "&A2&" ")))
```

Again both work in Excel, not sure about librecalc.  The first will do fewer interactions if the string has less words than the lookup list, while the second is the opposite

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For LO Calc:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2:B$5;A2)))
```

[image: 3,1,1,1]