# Vlookup with Wild card {*} in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the below table:

[image]

Now, I want to check if the subject is having any of the text present in data (col F)

I used:-

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"*",F:F,1,0)
```

But it is giving **#N/A**.

Comment: Other way around - you need to look up column F against column A. You can use a similar approach to that demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109606).

Comment: @BigBen I see that its only when we are sure that we need to find within x cells. What if I add more rows to column F? then I need to change the formula all the tme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,F$2:F$3&"*"))>0
```

Edit:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,F$2:INDEX(F:F,MATCH("ZZZ",F:F))&"*"))>0
```

Comment: what if I have value in F4 and other rows in the future? I would need to change the formula always?

Comment: @NotSure, or you could make values in F into an actual table you refer to or you could for example use a nested `INDEX()` `MATCH()` combination to establish the last used row in the column dynamically.

Comment: nested worked very well, just want to check what result you get when you have *Escalation HC 08 23 2022* in your `A4` cell. For me, it's giving result as false.

Comment: Returns `TRUE` as it supposed to for me @NotSure

Comment: Please check ss:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkp4.png

Comment: @NotSure, the only reason I can think of is that you haven't confirmed the formula using `CSE`. Either do that or use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead of `SUM()`.